# HTML5 Geolocation lat/lon in url

Tags: javascript, string, html, url, geolocation

How can I add **lat** and **lon**  variables in this url:

```
<a class="geo" href="http://dev.site.com/geolocation?distance[latitude]=LAT&distance[longitude]=LON&distance[search_distance]=20&distance[search_units]=km">GPS</a>
```

javascript from: http://jsfiddle.net/yJrtR/14/

```
window.onload = function () {
  var latElement = document.getElementById("lat"),
      lonElement = document.getElementById("lon"),
      lastUpdatedElement = document.getElementById("last_updated"),
      watchPositionOptions = {
          enableHighAccuracy: false,
          timeout: 10000,
          maximumAge: 0
      };
  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
      console.log("Successfully retrieved position: ", position);
      var coords = position.coords;

      latElement.innerHTML = coords.latitude;
      lonElement.innerHTML = coords.longitude;

      lastUpdatedElement.innerHTML = new Date(position.timestamp);
  }, function (error) {
      console.log("Something went wrong retrieving position: ", error);
  }, watchPositionOptions);
};
```

Comment: Do you mean to add the values of `LAT` and `LON` to the `href` of the `<a>`?

Comment: Yes, is this possible? I try with this jQuery-code: $("a.target").attr("href", "http://dev.site.com/geolocation?distance[latitude]=LAT&distance[longitude]=LON...");  
  }); Or is it better in a IMG-tag?

Comment: Are you continually monitoring position? You may be better off using a function instead of an <a> so that you can use the latest lat/LNG instead of continually rewriting the href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct the URL with concatenated strings like:

```
var URL = "http://dev.site.com/geolocation?";
URL =+ "distance[latitude]=" + LAT;
URL =+ "&distance[longitude]=" + LON;
URL =+ "&distance[search_distance]=20&distance[search_units]=km";
```

Then set the `href=` to `URL` with jQuery

```
 $("a.target").attr("href", URL);
```

or by modifying the attribute in javascript.